# Overridden getter doesn't fire other selectors

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Suppose I have a property `foo` and an associated ivar `_foo`.

I overrode the getter for foo in the following manner:

```
- (fooType*)foo {
  [_foo bar];
  return _foo;
}
```

Yet when I set a symbolic breakpoint for `bar`, it never fires. Wondering why that's the case.

Comment: do you mean you have an @synthesize foo = _foo and then are over-riding the synthesized foo?

Comment: Are you accessing foo using [self foo] or self.foo?

Comment: I tried both, and neither one works

Comment: When you set the breakpoint for `foo` does it stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: Nope I tried both symbolic and regular breakpoints and it stopped at neither

Comment: @Steve `[self foo]` is the same as `self.foo`. The compiler processes `self.foo` as exactly `[self foo]`. Dot syntax is simply a convenience Objective-C 2.0 took from Java so that it's easier to travel references.

Comment: @JackLawrence I'm aware of that, I was asking if he was using either of those, rather than referring to _foo in his code, to ensure he was accessing the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object you're calling `foo` on is nil, you won't get in this method. Similarly, if `_foo` is nil, you won't get into `bar`.

Try putting a breakpoint where you're calling `foo` and look at the object you're calling it on. Then you can also try stepping into the call to foo.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. I checked right before the getter fires to make sure self.foo is not nil, and indeed it's not nil. But when I call the getter I get a nil result.

Comment: Wait you checked if `self.foo` is not nil or did you check that `_foo` is not nil?

Comment: Turns out I was missing a key initialization step. I should have indeed verified that _foo was not nil. Your solution pointed me to the right fix. Thanks!